# how to launch screen and then execute a command inside this screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

When I type in:

```
screen -S game;ls;
```

However the '`ls`' command is executed outside the screen.

How can I start the 'game' screen and execute the `ls` command inside the screen ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
screen [ -options ] [ cmd [ args ] ]
```

example: `screen -S game ls`

Comment: problem is : that solution start screen, execute ls and close the screen. Any idea on how not to close the screen, but ONLY detach it ?

Comment: -d -m   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

Comment: example: `screen -S test -d -m cat /dev/urandom`

Comment: screen session will exists until `cat /dev/urandom` not terminated